# Given a ring with unity and a central idempotent element e, prove some isomorphic relations

Tags: ring-theory, idempotents

Given a ring $R$ with  $1\neq  0$, and an element $e$ that is idempotent which is central in $R$, I want to prove that $R/Re \cong R(1-e)$, $R/R(1-e)\cong Re$, and subsequently, $R\cong Re\times R(1-e)$. My intuition is pointing me to the isomorphism theorems, and the last should follow from the Chinese remainder theorem, but I'm at a loss as to how to connect the dots.

Comment: Your plan is fine. Where are you stuck?

Comment: It would make much more sense to prove $R\cong Re\times R(1-e)$ and *then* subsequently prove the two quotient isomorphisms.

Comment: @rschwieb It seems fairly natural to prove it this way as well... (If you're proving both statements)

Comment: Dear @jgon : It is certainly possible to do it in the order suggested in the OP. But since you can prove the ring decomposes into two pieces elementarily, and then the two quotient ring isomorphisms follow immediately from the first isomorphism theorem, it seems objectively simpler to do it in the order I'm describing. Doing it in the other order provides an application of the CRT, but it is slightly harder. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb I suppose, I learned ring theory from number theory, so first isomorphism theorem and CRT are the most natural algebraic tools for me to think about. Regards

Answer (score 3):

You can prove directly that $R\cong Re\times R(1-e)$. The natural map works:

> Let $f=1-e$. Then $e+f=1$ and $ef=0=fe$. Consider $\phi: R\to Re\times R(1-e)$ given by $\phi(x)=(xe,xf)$. it is easy to see that $\phi$ is injective. To prove that it is surjective, prove that $\phi(ye+zf)=(ye,zf)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your ideas are exactly right.

First note that since $e$ is central, $Re$ and $R(1-e)$ are two sided ideals. Since $1\in Re+R(1-e)$.

To show that $R/Re \cong R(1-e)$, note that $\varphi(x)=x(1-e)$ is a homomorphism of rings (since $\varphi(xy)=x(1-e)y(1-e)=xy(1-e)$). Note that $Re \subset \ker \varphi$ since $\varphi(xe)=xe(1-e)=x(e-e)=x0=0$.
Then we want to use the first isomorphism theorem (since $\varphi$ is clearly surjective), so we just need $\ker\varphi= Re$. Suppose $x\in\ker\varphi$, then $x(1-e)=0$, or $x-xe=0$, but then $x=xe$, so $x\in Re$. Therefore $\ker\varphi=Re$ and by the first isomorphism theorem $R/Re\cong R(1-e)$. The other proof is identical.

Now we just need the last statement.
Note that we want the intersection of the ideals to be trivial to use the Chinese remainder theorem to get what we want. To see this, note that multiplying by $e$ is the identity on $Re$ since $e$ is idempotent, however $x(1-e)e=x(e-e)=x0=0$, so no element of $R(1-e)$ can be in $Re$ except 0. Thus the intersection is trivial. We also have $Re+R(1-e)=R$, so by the Chinese remainder theorem $R\cong R/(0)=R/(I\cap J) \cong R/Re \times R/R(1-e)\cong R(1-e)\times Re$.